# Error "Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks." while using module Playsound

Tags: python, python-playsound

So basically this my code:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('C:\\Users\\arnavb\\Desktop\\Python\\Lecture1\\song.mp3')
```

And the error I get is:

```
PS C:\Users\arnavb\Desktop\Python> & C:/Users/arnavb/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/arnavb/Desktop/Python/Lecture1/Practice_3.py

    Error 305 for command:
        open "C:\Users\arnavb\Desktop\Python\Lecture1\song.mp3"
    Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.

    Error 263 for command:
        close "C:\Users\arnavb\Desktop\Python\Lecture1\song.mp3"
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
Failed to close the file: "C:\Users\arnavb\Desktop\Python\Lecture1\song.mp3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\arnavb\Desktop\Python\Lecture1\Practice_3.py", line 2, in <module>
    playsound('C:\\Users\\arnavb\\Desktop\\Python\\Lecture1\\song.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\arnavb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
  File "C:\Users\arnavb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 305 for command:
        open "C:\Users\arnavb\Desktop\Python\Lecture1\song.mp3"
    Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.
```

Comment: Btw the Python version is 3.9.6

Comment: Try:- playsound(r'C:\Users\arnavb\Desktop\Python\Lecture1\song.mp3')

Comment: It looks like some internal function is quoting the path because of the embedded backslashes. Try this instead: `playsound('C:/Users/arnavb/Desktop/Python/Lecture1/song.mp3')`.

Comment: PS: in fact, on Windows, playsound *always* adds double-quotes: https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/master/playsound.py#L31. It seems like a bug that the documentation doesn't mention this. To get the input path right, it means you should either use forward-slashes or explicitly escape all backslashes, like this: `playsound(r'C:\\Users\\arnavb\\Desktop\\Python\\Lecture1\\song.mp3')` or this `playsound('C:\\\\Users\\\\arnavb\\\\Desktop\\\\Python\\\\Lecture1\\\\song.mp3')`.

Answer (score 9):

Follow this steps :

```
pip uninstall playsound
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Comment: This works. Thanks!